# Difference between created response in Silverstripe

Tags: php, content-management-system, silverstripe

After testing the code below produces the same results. My question is, is there a difference between the two at all?

```
 public function someaction1(SS_HTTPRequest $request) {
        $this->setResponse(new SS_HTTPResponse());
        $this->getResponse()->setStatusCode(400);
        $this->getResponse()->setBody('invalid');

        return $this->getResponse();
    }

    public function someaction2(SS_HTTPRequest $request) {
        $this->response = new SS_HTTPResponse();
        $this->response->setStatusCode(400);
        $this->response->setBody('invalid');

        return $this->response;
    }
```

To add, is return $this->response; or return $this->getResponse(); necessary or are they implicit?

Comment: getX() and setX() are [Mutator methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutator_method), read [why to use them](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568091/why-use-getters-and-setters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference, just open the parent class definition and see what getResponse() does:

```
public function getResponse() {
    return $this->response;
}
```

When you want to return HTTP error, it is better to use

```
$this->httpError(400, 'invalid request');
```

(no need to return, since it throws exception)